# Set domain alias for analytics?

Tags: php, nginx, matomo

Matomo (formerly Piwik) is an analytics engine. I can generate tracking links to embed into websites. Identical to Google Analytics, just private.

I have 2 websites, A and B. On website A, I can login to A.com/analytics and generate a tracking key. Next I can embed that key into website B, now I am monitoring website B from website A.

Similar to how Google Analytics runs from analytics.google.com, if that script is block Analytics break. On website B, it says there is analytics script running linked to website A.

(This was poorly explained)
How can I create an alias so the analytics is running from website B, although it's actually on website A? I don't want a visitor to see that analytics are running from A.com. I want it to say B.com, like all the other scripts.

The websites are on the same VPS, running Nginx. Should I change the link to an IP address instead of "A.com/alaytics script", or symlink the analytics directory to /var/www/B.com?

I'd like to have analytics it's own root directory under /var/www and have subdomains symlinked to it (analytics.b.com). But this is a future endeavor.

Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your issue, but this may help: https://github.com/matomo-org/tracker-proxy

Comment: Wow Lukas, thank you so much. This seems like exactly what I need. Excellent, thanks!